# Extrair dados de raster a partir de um shape no R

Tags: r

Como fazer para extrair dados de raster a partir de um shape? */

```
printf("%d\n", 42);  /* Como fazer para extrair dados de raster a partir de um shape
```

Comment: Sua pergunta não está clara.  Por favor, defina qual tipo de shape, raster etc. Coloque algum exemplo do dado que deseja fazer a transformação.

Comment: tenho um arquivo tif e tenho um polygono dentro do raster.

Comment: realmente, não da pra entender nem um pouco a sua pergunta cara, tenta mandar uma versão toy do seu código para agnt lhe dar um help

Answer (score 0):

Olá, provavelmente o que você quer é um mask

```
library(raster)
#raster exemplo
r<-raster(ncol=10,nrow=10)
r[]<-1:ncell(r)
plot(r)
#poligono exemplo
pol<-raster(ncol=2,nrow=2)
pol[]<-1:ncell(pol)
pol<-as(pol,"SpatialPolygons")[1]
plot(r);plot(pol,add=T)
#crop ou mask para cortar
c1<-crop(r,pol)
m1<-mask(r,pol)
#mask nao altera o extent, o crop sim

#retornar valores do raster cortado
v1<-values(c1) #valores sem NA 
v2<-values(m1) #valores com NA
```